# How to get an equation of a line, given an equation for y and an equation for x?

Tags: graphing-functions

I have to generate a graph, with $y = e^{a\cdot t} - 1$    and $x = e^{b\cdot t} - 1 $
for all possible values of t. Constants a & b are given. 
In other words, the curve generated will be the locus of all points having all possible values of t.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would this include strange values of t like $i$?  There is the question of what is the domain of t as you don't state whether t could be complex or not.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that $a,b$ are real constants and $t$ is a real variable.

You could invert the formula for $x$, to get
$$t = \frac {\log (x+1)} b$$
and then plug it in the formula for $y$, to get
$$y = \exp\left({\frac a b \log (x+1)}\right) - 1 = (x+1)^{a/b} - 1$$

The domain for this formula is $x > -1$.